# Is it possible for a ListView to loop back to the beginning of a finite list to create infinite scrolling in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have a settings screen where the user can select 1 of 5 possible images which are laid out in a horizontal ListView. The images are too wide for the screen so the ListView scrolls horizontally.

I am going for a 'lazy Susan' effect where if you keep scrolling left, it just infinitely scrolls through the same 5 options (A B C D E A B C D E A B C...).

Is it possible to set up infinite scrolling on a finite list?

I've spent ages researching but infinite scrolling only seems to be a concept when pulling from the web or generating content programmatically and I just want to infinitely scroll through my 5 items...

Answer (score 6):

Just use `ListView.builder` with a builder callback returns the same items in a loop.  For example:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (buildContext, index) {
    return listOfWidgets[index % listOfWidgets.length];
  },
),
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the suggestion unfortunately it hasnt worked for me. Isn't % the modulo operator so it's just returning the remainder of the divisions between the index and the list length? (which confuses me because i'd expect that to break it)

Comment: @AlexCretney Yes, the `%` is the modulo operator.  For example, if you have a sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... and then apply say, `% 3` to each value, you'd get a new sequence 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, ....

Comment: @AlexCretney Also, if it isn't working, perhaps you could edit your question to provide more specific details about what you tried and how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PageView.builder or ListView.builder(just swap Pageview. builder with Listview.builder & no need to change controller) and initialPageNumber represet how many time you can scroll back (backward scroll)  and forward scroll is infinite

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({
        Key? key,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final List<Container> yourWidgets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
          .map((e) => Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text(
                  'text $e',
                ),
              ))
          .toList();
    
      final initialPageNumber = 1000; //how many times you can scroll back
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: PageView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: PageController(
                initialPage: initialPageNumber,
                viewportFraction: 0.2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return yourWidgets[((i - initialPageNumber) < 0
                        ? (i - initialPageNumber) + yourWidgets.length
                        : (i - initialPageNumber)) %
                    yourWidgets.length];
              },
            ),
          ),
          // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can but it takes some workaround, which I had to do but it became ugly very fast. Easiest way is to use the carousel slider package.
https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Comment: Thanks krumpli, thanks i did look at that. The problem with carousel is that i think it only allows a single image on screen at once.. i.e 1 in the center, 2 on the absolute periphery of the screen.. each image is about a 3'rd of the width of my screen that would result in far too much white space. Im looking for infinity scrolling of 5 images with 3 in view at all times... im pretty hard to satisfy! ;) ha ha

Comment: I don't know if this would help but i found this:
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_infinite_listview